# import json file into mongodb [ missing ; before statement @<shell> ]

Tags: json, mongodb

It is the first time I use mongodb.
I want to insert a zip.json file into mongodb running one of the commands bellow, and I get error.

```
mongoimport --db test --collection zips --file \C:\Install\advanced programs\mongodb\zips.json

mongoimport --db test --collection zips --type json --file \C:\Install\advanced programs\mongodb\zips.json
```

The error:

[image: capture]

To run these commands I oppened a cmd in `bin` directory of mongodb and I ran mongo.

Comment: Hey, did you found any solution to this issue? I am facing the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

you should use double quotation `""` for file path because your file path contained space and no need to extra back slash `\C:\` just use `C:\`

use

```
mongoimport --db test --collection zips --file "C:\Install\advanced programs\mongodb\zips.json"
```

instead of

```
mongoimport --db test --collection zips --file \C:\Install\advanced programs\mongodb\zips.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your json is not valid? Looks like there is an extra quote somewhere. Try validating it using [any online service](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to start different cmd and go to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin or it should be in ur path and then u need to run "mongoimport" command. If you start using "mongoimport" from "mongo" shell then it will not work.